# Increasing Fluidity 2D game Java

Tags: java, graphics

Im trying to code a 2D pong game with java. The problem that i have is about fluidity. Im using images (As most of the 2D games do) for background and paddles and the ball. Created the game with the Actionlistener and attached it with a timer to the game. For now i just have this code in the game loop for collision.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (ball.y <= 0 || ball.y + ball.height + 35 > HEIGHT) { // Horizontal
                                                                // Walls
                                                                // collision
        ballspeedY = -ballspeedY;
    }
    if (ball.x <= 0 || ball.x + ball.width + 5 >= WIDTH) { // Vertical Walls
                                                            // collision
        ballspeedX = -ballspeedX;
    }

    ball.y += ballspeedY;
    ball.x += ballspeedX;

    renderer.repaint();
}
```

And this code for drawing

```
public void repaint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);

    g2d.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
    g2d.drawImage(ball.image, ball.x, ball.y, ball.width, ball.height, null);
    g2d.drawImage(paddle.image, paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.width, paddle.height, null);
}
```

The problem is, when i increase the ball's speed, it starts to move not smoothly. Ive done a research and tried to cancel drawing the background image. And the ball started to move a bit more smooth. The thing im confused about is, what if i have moving background or 100 balls or something else. Im doing something wrong and please someone tell me which way i should use to move these objects on the screen smoothly. The games which are using a lot bigger images or backgrounds or even 3D games move so fluidly but my simple pong game doesn't. What am i doing wrong?

**SOLVED:** The problem is just with this line:
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);

This line cracks the animations fluidity. When i delete it, everthing runs pretty fast and smooth

Comment: When you say that the ball isn't moving smoothly, is it flickering, or does it appear to jump from one position to the next instead of appearing to slide continuously?

Comment: Not flickering, like the second argument you said. Jumping from one position to the next, instead of sliding smootly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't fully answer your question, because that is actually a complicated subject. There are multiple different aspects to talk about, but each of them is in itself studying material. I'll try to cover the basic ideas:

**Multithreading**

So first of all, your code is probably executed all sequential. Each time `actionPerformed` runs, it will call `redraw` at the end. Now, basically this will define your 'framerate'. So the more time consuming (more complex code) your `actionPerformed` is, the lower your framerate will get.

To counter this, one thread on it's own can take care to draw the actual state of the game.

**Ball speed is not related to the framerate**

I am not sure how to read your code. But from what I see, your ballspeed is an integer. Take in account the thing I wrote above. So in your current implementation ballspeed actually defines how far the ball moves *per frame*. That is a problem, because it would mean, that the game runs faster/slower depending on the complexity of `actionPerformed`. Even if I read your code wrong, this is a thing to consider.

One way to solve it, is to separate calculation and drawing with multiple threads like mentioned above. But you should probably also have a look at [frame independent physics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/94000/how-to-implement-accurate-frame-rate-independent-physics).

**100 balls problem**

If you would calculate the positions of all x balls in your `actionPerformed` method, your framerate becomes increasingly slower the bigger x gets. This, again, is because of the things above. But I guess at one point you have to do further optimizations, otherwise your recalculation process can't keep up. Though the number should be quite high - but this is where I lack experience.

**Graphics2D is not OpenGL**

I am not too familiar with how the Java Graphics2D works, but I have basic knowledge about OpenGL. For real games OpenGL is almost a must. Even webgames start to use WebGL (browser supported interface for similar functionality). This is where you actually use the graphics card for its capabilities. Especially for 3D games, but even for simple 2D games it is really the best for performance. By the way, smartphones games as well.

Covering that would be impossible here, so I just leave it as is. If you are interested in those things, you would need to learn them more in depth. I guess your next step would be to use a framerate independent calculation. I'm not sure about the multithreading stuff, because it usually comes along with a bunch of difficulties...

Comment: First of all, thanks for this kinda guiding. I really got some points in your explanation. And researched a bit about OpenGL. And now im about to decide for switching to that library. Because i basicly got the idea of how simple games are programmed. The thing i wanna ask for last is, are there any proper tutorials (especially with videos) about this library? I mean, for example how did you learn OpenGL as a beginner?

Comment: @TolgaŞen To be completely honest, I had the chance to learn it in my computer science studies. I guess if you want to create a simple java game with openGL, try using JOGL (http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/). It was the library I used first. But let me just say, OpenGL is really complicated. So maybe you start better off with your java Graphics2D approach. Sorry about not having a tutorial, maybe you find one on the JOGL page.